# Finding directory of Python script from QGIS Python Console

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I will be importing some CSV files from the directory of the script that I have opened on Python Console on QGIS. Yet, I cannot access the true directory with `os.getcwd()` or something else.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `Path(__file__).parent`? (`from pathlib2 import Path`)

Comment: @DannyVarod I have tried. But it gives the wrong path. For instance, my python file is in the desktop. All the methods I try found it in the documents. I think it is because of the QGIS idle and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The QGIS python console is an emulated python console (python plugin).

To do that it's a little bit tricky and I didn't find an other way :

```
import os
from console.console import _console

script_path = _console.console.tabEditorWidget.currentWidget().path
print(os.path.dirname(script_path))
```

**NB** :This sample example only works when the tabEditor is opened and the script is saved on the disk.

Comment: returning a blank string in QGIS 3.22.8